# Rails integration tests failing when selenium-webdriver enabled and passing when omitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, devise, capybara

I have following integration test written using RSpec & Capybara and it is failing with `js: true` and passing when I omit it.

When I test the application manually it is working fine. The user gets redirected from `/` to `/signin` as soon as the Rails 4 server starts at `http://localhost:3000`. The user is validated using devise gem.

Is there some problem with gem dependencies? Am I missing anything?

**Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
  gem 'i18n-tasks'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
```

**login_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature "Login:", js: true do
  scenario "-display login page to the user" do
    visit "/"
    expect(page).to have_xpath("//input[@type='email']")
    expect(page).to have_xpath("//input[@type='password']")
    expect(page).to have_content("Login to Dashboard")
    expect(page).to have_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']")
    expect(page).to have_content("Forgot your password?")
  end
end
```

**Command to run spec:**

```
rspec -b spec/feature/login_spec.rb
```

**Error Log:**

```
    Failures:

      1) Login: -display login page to the user
         Failure/Error: raise ActionController::RoutingError, "No route matches [#{env['REQUEST_METHOD']}] #{env['PATH_INFO'].inspect}"

         ActionController::RoutingError:
           No route matches [HEAD] "/assets/login_header-117f87e381545e9f6d5a7accb7aa72188a0304644af6891c42e1cd57f38fad67@2x.jpg"
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/request_store-1.3.0/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:66:in `block in call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `each'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:50:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/server.rb:19:in `call'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
         # C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
         # ------------------
         # --- Caused by: ---
         # Capybara::ExpectationNotMet:
         #   expected to find xpath "//input[@type='checkbox']" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.
         #   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/matchers.rb:97:in `block in assert_selector'
```

**Original Page Html**

```
<!-- Login Block -->
  <div class="block push-bit">
    <!-- Login Form -->
    <form class="form-horizontal form-bordered form-control-borderless" id="new_user" action="/signin" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="56u6N33zmqwC3dEO3Nh7aZZqOIRgtphs/hoRXKXP3QRKZ2OfgZ6FpGPpFb6FiMc95DfWD/oOWvZVoepqbivjzw==" />

                <div class="alert
    alert-danger
     alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
  <span id="alert-msg">You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.</span>
</div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="gi gi-envelope"></i></span>
              <input label="Email:" wrapper="{:class=&gt;&quot;required&quot;}" id="login-email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="user[email]" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="gi gi-asterisk"></i></span>
              <input label="Password:" wrapper="{:class=&gt;&quot;required&quot;}" id="login-password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="user[password]" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group form-actions">
          <div class="col-xs-4">

                <label class="switch switch-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remember Me?">
                  <input name="login-remember-me" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="login-remember-me" name="login-remember-me" type="checkbox" value="1" />
                  <span></span>
                </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-8 text-right">
            <button name="button" type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="login">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Login to Dashboard
</button>          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">

    <a id="link-reminder-login" href="/users/password/new">Forgot your password?</a><br />

          </div>
        </div>
</form>    <!-- END Login Form -->


  </div>
  <!-- END Login Block -->
```

Answer (score 0):

First guess would be that you're hiding the checkbox on the page via CSS (and then styling the label to show it's selected).  The default rack-test driver doesn't process most CSS so it would still find the checkbox, but when you use js: true you're using a real browser which does process CSS.  You can try changing your test to

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox']" , visible: :all)
```

to see if that is the issue.  Seeing your html now it looks like you're using maybe bootstrap-switch(?) which does hide the real checkbox so you can either do above if all you care is that there is a checkbox.  Optionally you could check the html on the live page and see what html the library adds to the page, and check for some of that.  A mid position might be to check for the hidden checkbox, but check that it's inside the switch wrapper - something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('.boostrap-switch-container input[type="checkbox"]', visible: :hidden) # adjust class as necessary for the wrapper produced by the library
```

which would verify the JS for the switch has run, created it's wrapper, and hidden the checkbox inside it.

I do question why you're using xpaths for finding these elements, when you could be using the ids/names/labels/placeholders to find them and have things be more readable

Now that you've added the html -- looking at the password field, there is no actual <label> element - so label text is out, however any of the following should find the element

```
expect(page).to have_field("Password", type: 'password')  # placeholder
expect(page).to have_field("login-password", type: 'password')  # id
expect(page).to have_field("user[password]", type: 'password') # name
```

usually I would go with the first one since it's testing what the user should see.

Comment: I made both the changes you suggested above but now getting following exception. `Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: #   expected to find field "password" of type "password" but there were no matches`

Comment: That  was an example of how you could be writing tests. The first string would need to match the id/name/placeholder or label text of your password field - post your html if you want exact answers

Comment: Should I post the html with a new question altogether or should I modify the existing question?

Comment: Edited the original question by adding the actual html code.

Comment: @user2325154  Updated to match your html